# Displaying results created in if statements at the end - Java

Tags: java

I am new to java and i'm writing a program which would randomise 1-6 4 times, display each of the 4 dice, then add the highest 3.

I would like to display the scores (stats) all together at the end but I have generated the stats in the if and else if statements. Any advice on how I can improve my code to allow me to use the int variables stat1 stat2 etc. later

```
//stat1     
    System.out.println("Dice 1: " + dice1);
    System.out.println("Dice 2: " + dice2);
    System.out.println("Dice 3: " + dice3);
    System.out.println("Dice 4: " + dice4);

    if(dice1 <= dice2 && dice1 <= dice3 && dice1 <= dice4) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        int stat1 = dice2 + dice3 + dice4;
        System.out.println("Stat 1: " + stat1);
    }

    else if(dice2 <= dice1 && dice2 <= dice3 && dice2 <= dice4) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        int stat1 = dice1 + dice3 + dice4;
        System.out.println("Stat 1: " + stat1);
    }

    else if(dice3 <= dice1 && dice3 <= dice2 && dice3 <= dice4) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        int stat1 = dice1 + dice2 + dice4;
        System.out.println("Stat 1: " + stat1);
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        int stat1 = dice1 + dice2+ dice3;
        System.out.println("Stat 1: " + stat1);
    }
```

The code for each of the six stats is basically the same but with the next 4 dice variables replaing "dice1" "dice2" "dice3" "dice4".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things you can do to improve your code.

First off, lets store those dice values in a collection, such as a list.

```
List<Integer> dices=Arrays.asList(dice1,dice2,dice3,dice4);
```

This will allow you to work with your dices much easier. You can access any dice with

```
dices.get(0);//for dice 1
dices.get(1);//for dice 2 etc
```

Now, this is the fun part, instead of using all those terrible if statements, we can sort your collection just like this...

```
Collections.sort(dices);
```

This will order them from lowest to greatest. Much better.

Now, to add the 3 biggest.

```
int stat1=dices.stream().skip(1).mapToInt(i->i.intValue()).sum();
```

This is why we use collections. This creates a stream of your list, filters to just the last 3 by skipping the first (we know they are the biggest because of how we ordered it), then sum them up as follows. In total, our code could look like

```
List<Integer> dices=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            dices.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(6)+1);
        }
        Collections.sort(dices);
        int stat1=dices.stream().skip(1).mapToInt(i->i.intValue()).sum();
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println(stat1);
```

Now, for your actual question, keep in mind in the future that variables work in scopes. If you want to access it down the line, just initialise it outside at the top of your if statements. A note to remember in the future.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful and informative, definitely neatens up my code since six stats are rolled this way

Comment: Glad it helped :) @JDN

Answer (score 1):

```
int stat1;
System.out.println("Dice 1: " + dice1);
System.out.println("Dice 2: " + dice2);
System.out.println("Dice 3: " + dice3);
System.out.println("Dice 4: " + dice4);

if(dice1 <= dice2 && dice1 <= dice3 && dice1 <= dice4) {
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    stat1 = dice2 + dice3 + dice4;
   // System.out.println("Stat 1: " + stat1);
}

else if(dice2 <= dice1 && dice2 <= dice3 && dice2 <= dice4) {
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    stat1 = dice1 + dice3 + dice4;
   // System.out.println("Stat 1: " + stat1);
}

else if(dice3 <= dice1 && dice3 <= dice2 && dice3 <= dice4) {
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    stat1 = dice1 + dice2 + dice4;
    //System.out.println("Stat 1: " + stat1);
}

else {
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    stat1 = dice1 + dice2+ dice3;
    //System.out.println("Stat 1: " + stat1);
}
 System.out.println("Stat 1: " + stat1);
```

You have to declare/initialize those variables like `stat1`, `stat2` etc before the if-else statement.Because they are local to the `if-else` blocks only. You cannot use them after the `if` gets completed. You can declare them in `main()` method itself. So,they will remain in the memory stack until `main()` methods get completed.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. Seems right for the question as it is. @rahul_vyas: can you perhaps illustrate it with code?

Answer (score 1):

You can move your logic to a function

```
 private int displayAndReturnStat(int dice1, int dice2, int dice3, int dice4, int statNum) {
    System.out.println("Dice 1: " + dice1);
    System.out.println("Dice 2: " + dice2);
    System.out.println("Dice 3: " + dice3);
    System.out.println("Dice 4: " + dice4);

    int stat;
    if(dice1 <= dice2 && dice1 <= dice3 && dice1 <= dice4) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        stat = dice2 + dice3 + dice4;
        System.out.println("Stat " + statNum + " : " + stat);
    }

    else if(dice2 <= dice1 && dice2 <= dice3 && dice2 <= dice4) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        stat = dice1 + dice3 + dice4;
        System.out.println("Stat " + statNum + " : " + stat);
    }

    else if(dice3 <= dice1 && dice3 <= dice2 && dice3 <= dice4) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        stat = dice1 + dice2 + dice4;
        System.out.println("Stat " + statNum + " : " + stat);
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        stat = dice1 + dice2+ dice3;
        System.out.println("Stat " + statNum + ": " + stat);
    }
    return stat;
}
```

and call as

```
int stat1 = displayStat(/*dice values*/, 1); //Stat1
int stat2 = displayStat(/*dice values*/, 2); //Stat2
int stat3 = displayStat(/*dice values*/, 3); //Stat3
int stat4 = displayStat(/*dice values*/, 4); //Stat4
```

For the fun of using Streams (logic is to find the minimum dice and sum the values of all dice except the smallest one)

```
private int displayAndReturnStat(int dice1, int dice2, int dice3, int dice4, int statNum) {
    System.out.println("Dice 1: " + dice1);
    System.out.println("Dice 2: " + dice2);
    System.out.println("Dice 3: " + dice3);
    System.out.println("Dice 4: " + dice4);

    int minDice = Stream.of(dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4)
            .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .get(); //Calling get won't throw an exception here as the Stream is guaranteed to be not empty
    int stat = Stream.of(dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4)
            .filter(diceValue -> diceValue != minDice)
            .mapToInt(diceValue -> diceValue)
            .sum();
    System.out.println("Stat " + statNum + ": " + stat);
    return stat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the outputted stat is just the sum without the minimum, so you can add them all together and then subtract the minimum afterwards.

```
int minValue = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (int currentDie : new int[] { dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4 }) {
     sum += currentDie;
     minValue = Math.min(currentDie, minValue);
}
sum -= minValue;
System.out.println("Stat 1: " + sum);
```

You'd usually do this in a function, like

```
public static int sum(int... dice) {
    int minValue = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int currentDie : dice) {
         sum += currentDie;
         minValue = Math.min(currentDie, minValue);
    }
    sum -= minValue;
    return sum;
}
```

and then call it like

```
int sum = sum(dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4);
System.out.println("Stat 1: " + sum);
```